# macOS Topbar "Refresh" dropdown menu selection to cause WKWebView refreshing?

Tags: macos, swiftui, wkwebview, menuitem

I'm trying to figure out how to map a Topbar menu selection to run a function. That function, in this case, would be to force WKWebView to refresh itself.

I'm not at all sure where to start from.
Main.storyboard allows me to delete, modify or add Topbar dropdown menus, so I have created a Refresh entry to the File -menu.

I've mapped it to CMD-R - since that feels like the most intuitive shortcut to run for Refresh.
[image: Refresh Menu Item in Topbar]

If I ctrl-click on the Refresh -item in the hierarchy in Main.storyboard - I can connect it to First Responder and select reloadFromOrigin.

After building the app, pressing CMD-R will refresh the WKWebView.
However, the Menu item itself is not enabled, it just shows as grayed out. After pressing CMD-R once, the menu item is enabled.

How do I make it "be enabled" at the start of the app?